# getting error when try insert row in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My function :

```
-(void)insertDownloadedActions:(NSMutableArray *)dataToAdd
{


    int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSInteger currentCount = self.dataSource.count;//getting error :" property 'dataSource' not found on object type xxxViewController"

        for (int i = 0; i < dataToAdd.count; i++) {
            [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentCount+i inSection:0]];
        }


        [self.dataSource addObjects:dataToAdd]; //getting error :" property 'dataSource' not found on object type xxxViewController"


        [tblListResult beginUpdates];
        [tblListResult insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [tblListResult endUpdates];
    });
}
```

I was add `UITableViewDatasource` in <> of .h file. How to fix that ? 
what is wrong ? thank you

Comment: what is the error description ?

Comment: You must not have a property named `dataSource` on your view controller. Why do you think there would be one if you don't add one?

Comment: @thndrkiss The error is in the code comment.

Comment: yeah can you try declaring an array and point it in your cellForRowAtIndex, in the above method and numberOfRowsInSection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableView` itself having a property known as `dataSource`. Please look at the Apple's doc

**dataSource**

The object that acts as the data source of the receiving table view.

*@property(nonatomic, assign) id dataSource*

**Discussion**

The data source must adopt the UITableViewDataSource protocol. The data source is not retained.

**Availability**

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
See Also
  @property delegate

**Declared In**

UITableView.h

so simply rename **your own** `dataSource` to other name something like `dataList`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not declared the 'dataSource' instance properly. Xcode says it could not able to find any instance in the name of 'dataSource'.

Replace `self. dataSource`  with just `dataSource`

Comment: This would only work if there was an ivar named `dataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a NSMutableArray in your Interface from your ViewController and initialize the array (e.g. in your viewDidLoad).

```
@interface ViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataSource;
@end


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.dataSource = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```